# Strange Gallery Folder

Tags: gallery, lg-g2

Every once in a while, a folder simply titled "Images" Will appear in my LG G2's gallery. It comes back even after I delete it.

For reference: [http://imgur.com/e5s0IOc](https://imgur.com/e5s0IOc)

Is this just Android being Android, or is an app causing this?

Thanks

Comment: The image is 404

Answer (score 0):

Check if any application you installed creates this folder. For example, "Easy Battery Saver" app creates its own image and video folders when you open it. I suspect, there is some application, which when you access, creates this folder.